# Interpretation of p-value histogram for differential methylation analysis: what can explain prevalence of large p-values?

Tags: r, t-test, p-value, skewness, bioinformatics

I am conducting an analysis of methylation data for ~20k+ genes.

For n=3, I am doing a t-test for every gene to see if it has been differentially methylated after treatment. Methylation values range from [0,1].

So, in my data I have 6 rows, with a before and after row for each patient and # columns = # of genes (~20k).

Here is code for generating p-values:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df))
{
  alpha = c(df[c(1,3,5),i])
  beta = c(df[c(2,4,6),i])
  df.p[i] = t.test(alpha,beta,paired=TRUE)$p.value
}

hist(df.p)
```

This churns out the p-values just fine, but when I make a histogram of the resulting p-values, it is skewed strongly to the left, which is strange since you'd at least expect a uniform distribution if you didn't have any significant methylation differences. Below is a screenshot of the distribution.

[image]

Side note: I've also used the `limma` package in `BioConductor` and got the same results.

Am I conducting the t-test wrong? How am I to interpret these results? Any advice is appreciated, as I am a novice biostatistician.

Comment: Related (but none of the existing answers can apply to the paired t-test): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63786.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: As Amoeba pointed out there was an error in my code, and the first plot is from an** *unpaired* **t-test. I re-ran with paired t-tests and different alpha and beta, and the results are at the bottom.**

I simulated it in Matlab with the code below. I generated 1000 random alphas (1x3 vectors); corresponding betas are made by adding a smaller-magnitude, random 1x3 vector to each alpha. The result is that alpha and beta are correlated. The resulting p-value distribution is given here (**unpaired** t-test). As you can see it's skewed to near-1 values.

**Unpaired t-test**

[image]

```
pp = zeros(1000,1);
for iter = 1:1000
  alpha = rand(1,3);
  beta = alpha + rand(1,3)*.1;
  [~,pp(iter)] = ttest2(alpha,beta);
end
```

**Edit: Paired t-test**
[image]

```
pp = zeros(10000,1);
for iter = 1:10000
  alpha = randn(1,3);
  beta = alpha + [rand 0.1 -1*rand];
  [~,pp(iter)] = ttest(alpha,beta);
end
```

To achieve the right-skewed distribution with a paired t-test I had to make different assumptions about beta: `beta = alpha + [r1 0.1 r2]`, where $r1$ and $r2$ are uniform random numbers, and $r1$ is in the range [0 1] and $r2$ is in the range [-1 0]. That is $r1$ is always positive, $r2$ is always negative, and their combined effect on `alpha-beta` is, on average, 0. The effect is to fairly reproduce your original histogram.

If this actually describes your data, it means that if e.g. gene methylation is high in one replicate, it's low in another replicate. Which is weird. Although it could happen if your data is a ratio and you've swapped numerator and denominator in one replicate. To test that, can you make scatter plots / calculate correlation between each pair of replicates, i.e. between `df[1,]` and `df[3,]`, `df[1,]` and `df[5,]`, etc. If your replicates are good they should all have high *positive* correlation - if any are negatively correlated then that's evidence for swapping the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand. Aren't two samples supposed to be (positively) correlated whenever we run a paired t-test? I mean, that's the whole point of running a paired t-test, compared to an unpaired t-test: namely, paired test has higher power precisely when there is correlation due to pairing. Are you saying that one should expect to see such skewed distributions of p-values *under the null* for a paired t-test? That would be weird.

Comment: I don't have Matlab installed on the laptop I am currently working, but I ran your code in https://octave-online.net/ - I only get a matching histogram if I replace `ttest` with `ttest2`. Are you sure your plot matches the code?

Comment: @amoeba You're right! The original code block should say ``test2``, i.e. the first figure is from unpaired t-tests. That was a combination of errors and late-night editing. Things are corrected now. I re-ran with paired t-tests and different beta, and that's included now too.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code/images. However, I believe that your interpretation of what is happening here is pretty much entirely wrong. E.g. this "This distribution is possible if your two samples, alpha and beta, are correlated." must be wrong as I tried to explain in the comment above. I am thinking that what you see is probably because the assumptions of the t-test are grossly violated in the samples you generate: they are not normal but coming from the uniform distribution, and with very low $n$ t-test behaves weird.